# Python: Class: Calling a function in the same class

Tags: python, class, python-2.7

Good day..

I'm kinda struggling in my learning process in Class. Let me show my code, and what is happening.

```
from random import randint
print "Start"
class Simulation (object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bankroll= 5000
        self.bet=0
        self.betLevel= 0
        self.betList=[5,5,5,10,15,25,40,65,100]
        self.wlist=[]
        self.my_file=open("output.txt","w")
        self.winningNumber=0
        self.myNumber=[4,5,7,8]
        self.testCase=1
        self.my_file.write("Test case Bet Number Outcome Bankroll")
    def gamble(self):
        self.bet=self.betList[self.betLevel]
        if self.bankroll < 1000 :
            self.bet= 5
        self.winningNumber= randint(0,36)
        if self.winningNumber in self.myNumber:
            win()
        else:
            lose()
    def win(self):
        self.bankroll +=(17*self.bet)
        self.wlist= [self.testCase,self.bet,self.winningNumber,"WIN",self.bankroll]
        self.betLevel=0
        write()
    def lose(self):
        self.bankroll -=self.bet
        self.wlist= [self.testCase,self.bet,self.winningNumber,"LOSE",self.bankroll]
        self.betLevel +=1
        write()
    def write(self):
        self.my_file.write(" ".join(self.wlist))
    def startSimulation(self):
        for i in range (100):
            gamble()
        closeFile()
    def closeFile(self):
        self.my_file.close()

mySimulation= Simulation()
mySimulation.startSimulation()
print "DONE"
```

So in this code, I'm trying to simulating a roulette game, using a weird betting system. It works like Martingale, but instead of doubling, I follows Fibonacci sequence.

So my problem is that I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Roulette simulation\python 3.py", line 44, in <module>
    mySimulation.startSimulation()
  File "D:\Roulette simulation\python 3.py", line 38, in startSimulation
    gamble()
NameError: global name 'gamble' is not defined
```

My question. Why? I mean, I'm calling a function in the same class? Why I got the global error?

Answer (score 2):

Within a method, you have `self` as a reference to your instance. You can access methods on that instance through that reference:

```
self.gamble()
```

There is no global `gamble` function here; the method is part of the `Simulation` class. This applies to all methods; you'll have to call `closeFile`, `lose`, `win` and `write` on `self` as well, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
self.gamble()
```

in class functions,self means class itself(someone use 'cls' instead of 'self'), so **self.gamble** means gamble function of this class

if you want to run a function in the position of class attribution

```
>>> class P:
    name = 'name'
    def getage(self):
        return 18
    age = property(getage)


>>> p = P()
>>> p.age
18
>>>
```